# Multiple orders within same bar

Tags: pine-script

Suppose I open a long position and the following happen, all within the *same bar*:

1. I set a stop loss (say at previous candle low)
2. Price initially moves in my favor and I take a partial profit
3. As soon as I take the partial profit, I move my stop loss to breakeven
4. Finally price goes against me so I exit at breakeven

Is there a way to have these orders executed all within the same bar? I've tried a few things but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Without "look inside bar" there is impossible to make requested behaviour unfortunately.